# PyCharm's "Search Everywhere" does not show filename extensions

Tags: macos, pycharm, file-handling, file-extension

I am working with PyCharm on a Mac and for some reason, it does not show filename extensions for certain file types when I'm using the "Search Everywhere" functionality.

[image: Search Everywhere does not show filetype extension for Python file]

As you can see in this example, the file ending .txt for `requirements.txt` is being displayed, but the .py extension for `restapi_test.py` does not show up. I would like to see the file extension for all files.

I thought it might be coming from Mac, but I also enabled file extensions there as well.

[image: Enabled file system extension display on Mac Finder]

Any idea why this is happening? Is there a setting that changes this behavior or is it a bug?

Comment: Presumably it doesn't bother to show `.py` because most of the files in your PyCharm project are Python files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Known issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-32404, please vote for it (thumbs up near the title)